# How do I share a python script's imports with another script?

Tags: python, django, oop, import

Let's say I have a script1.py with imports.

How can I share script1.py imports with script2.py? without copy and pasting.

Comment: Split your Python program into modules?

Comment: Do you really **need** al those imports? Do you use all the types you are importing?

Comment: It seems (to me) that you should modularize your application a bit more ;)

Comment: Check my answer. Now it's edited. It might help.

Comment: Classic X, Y problem. What you should be asking is, "how can I reduce the number of dependencies?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application should consist of many modules that are logically independent. It makes your program easier to read, debug etc. Just like Python's standard library is divided into many modules (as you said - you have to import things from many of them).

The more modules you have, the fewer imports you need to do in each of them.
It's because each separate part of your program only imports what it needs. Thanks to this attitude you and other programmers can easily understand the code.

Another way to deal with it (not really recommended):

imports.py: (in this example I assume you put it in the same directory as test.py)

```
from datetime import date
from re import *
```

test.py:

```
from imports import * #you import your imports

today = date.today() #using what you imported in imports.py
print(today)
```

It might be dangerous due to possibly same names imported. Be careful!

Comment: This level of indirection is always confusing.  Having a "master imports" makes analysis of the code quite a bit harder because you can no longer do a simple "grep" to find the dependencies.

Comment: That's why I firstly recommended dividing into modules. And secondly doing something different.

Comment: The `imports.py` approach is a bad thing to do.  Your your answer presents it in a way that makes it look good.  I don't see very many warnings, so I added one in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

though I agree with the comments... you can have a module that defines the **all** attribute

```
from crazyapp import all, my, imports

__all__ =['all', 'my', 'imports']
```

then just call to import the modules.

`from allmyimports import *`

But fix things if you have that many.... 200? Think of a module as something that does one thing and does that one thing good. you'll find your imports will drop for the most part.

Comment: So, if my "crazyapp.py" has 200 imports, then on my other files....I can do "from crazyapp import all, my, imports" , and it will get crazyapp.py's imports?

Comment: @TIMEX, no, `from crazyapp import all, my, imports` only imports `all`, `my` and `imports`. If you want all of crazyapp, then `import crazyapp`, then use `crazyapp.x`, `crazyapp.y` and so on. I think what this answer is trying to show you is how you can control what the `from X import *` actually imports, which is the symbols defined by the `__all__` attribute of the module.